# Where to download Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator

I searched all the site of Android developers [where a download link is supposed to be](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), and I just found an endless loop of self references and no link.
And many blogs redirect to a campaign link that redirects to the same page.

I just want this SDK because of its emulator. Where to get it on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that page, there should be a large green button:

[image: Android Studio download page]

Clicking that button brings up a license dialog:

[image: Android Studio license dialog]

Checking the "agree" checkbox enables the button shown in blue. Clicking the button will begin your download.

These screenshots were taken using Firefox 47.0 on Ubuntu 15.10. Chromium 51.0 also works on Ubuntu 15.10.

There *was* a bug on the site last week, where the green download button was disabled on Linux. That bug has been fixed, though it is possible there is some combination of Linux distro and browser where the bug still exists.

Comment: thanks for your answer, there is no button, as is shown in [this image on imgur](http://i.imgur.com/lAoRyHF.png). (I link it since I am not still allowed to attach images)

Comment: @FahedFahed: You can also download stable versions of Android Studio from [the tools site](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable).

Comment: I use Firefox on Ubuntu, I thought it was blocked by Ligthbeam block being active, but disabling it made no difference.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can see links there, I am also trying rigth now to install it via Ubuntu make. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @FahedFahed This might be an issue with the developer web site. Can you try another browser? Also you should report this to Google.

Comment: @FahedFahed also can you add the screenshot to your OP?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice what do you mean by OP? Sorry but it's not clear to me :P

Comment: I think that the website is recognizing my computer as a mobile device, since the layout has the same parts.

Comment: @FahedFahed OP stands for Original Post

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Internet Explorer as your browser? This was the only scenario in which I was not able to download using the aforementinoned link.
If this is the case, try using another browser.

Comment: No, it is Firefox 48 on Ubuntu (KDE Neon) I don't know what it is, but the two options we mentioned in the other answer seem to work. Thanks for answering.